# Android RoomDatabase get SupportSQLiteDatabase exception

Tags: android, android-room

I'm using Room and I need to perform a database migration. I've migrated the data but I have a problem in one of the columns. When the migration is performed, the data for that column may still be unavailable.

When the user enters the data needed for that column, I have to get all rows that match a value in that column, update these values by the one provided by the user and drop all other rows that do not match.

I can have a method in my `UserDao` but the problem is that this does not seem correct because it's a one time only thing and I don't what to expose the method so my idea was to get the database instance and try to do the change myself.

When I use

```
var myDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(....)
.addMigrations(... .build()
```

I keep a reference to it but then, when I do `myDatabase.openHelper.writableDatabase` I'm always getting an exception

```
getDatabase called recursively
```

Any idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are trying to use the MyDatabase's openHelper to try to get the database when building the instance of MyDatabase which is in the process of getting the database, so while getting the database you are then trying to get the database.

Instead you need to use the SupportSQLiteDatabase that is passed to the Migration.

As ean example :-

```
@Database(
    version = 1,
    entities =  [
        MyTableEntity::class
    ]
)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun MyTableEntityDao(): MyTableEntityDao

    companion object {

        val MIGRATION_V1_V2: Migration = object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                //........ code using the already opened database
                database.execSQL(????????); //<<<<<<<<<< USES the support database
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would then be invoked using something similar to :-

```
    var myDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext,AppDatabase::class.java,"mydatabase")
        .allowMainThreadQueries()
        .addMigrations(AppDatabase.MIGRATION_V1_V2)
        .build()
```